# Oracle sql developer connection - Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I download oracle sql developer "Windows 64-bit with JDK 8 included" from oracle website /download section. I unzipped it and tried to make a connection. I tried couple of options but I am getting "Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" error.

Can any one help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a database?
[I downloaded SQL Developer, now what?](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/)

SQL Developer is just a client, you need a database to connect to.